# Detect overscroll or end of pages event in ViewPager2 android

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

there is no method for overscroll in `ViewPager2` I need to detect the overscroll so I can take the user back to home page once there are no more pages.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ViewPager2 does not have a public method for over scroll, however, It can be detected by listening to `onPageScrollStateChanged`

Usually transition of events in `onPageScrollStateChanged` for scroll state is `SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING` -> `SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING` -> `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` when changing a page

But in case of overscroll the sequence is  `SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING` -> `SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`

```
private fun listenOverScroll(currentIndex: Int, size: Int) {
        var index = currentIndex
        var previousState =  ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE
        viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                super.onPageSelected(position)
                index = position
            }

            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Index:: $index | state:: $state | prevState:: $previousState")
                super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state)
                if ((index >= size - 1 || index <= 0)// end of list. these checks can be 
                                                     // used individualy to detect end or start of pages
                        && previousState == ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING // from DRAGGING
                        && state == ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {          // to IDLE
                    Log.d(TAG,"OVERSCROLL:: Index:: $index | state:: $state | prevState:: $previousState")
                    //overscroll performed. do your work here
                }
                previousState = state
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a clearer and cleaner solution.

```
private fun viewPagerScrollStateListener() {
    binding.viewPager.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        private var scrolling = false

        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
            super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state)
            scrolling = when (state) {
                ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING -> true
                ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING -> true
                ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE -> {
                    if (scrolling && isLastPage()) {
                        // Scrolling has ended and we are on the last page
                        onEndScroll()
                    }
                    false
                }

                else -> false
            }
        }

        private fun isLastPage(): Boolean {
            return binding.viewPager.currentItem + 1 == adapter.itemCount
        }

        private fun onEndScroll() {
            Log.i("ViewPager", "End of scrolling")
        }
    })
}
```